# How do I encode a simple array into JSON in Perl?

Tags: json, perl

All the examples that I've seen of encoding objects to JSON strings in Perl have involved hashes. How do I encode a simple array to a JSON string?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
my @arr = ("this", "is", "my", "array");
my $json_str = encode_json(@arr);  # This doesn't work, produced "arrayref expected"

# $json_str should be ["this", "is", "my", "array"]
```

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* isn't a useful description of your problem. Please explain carefully what happens, and how it differs from what you require.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you run that code, you should get the following error:

```
hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this)
```

You simply need to pass a reference to your `\@arr`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @arr = ("this", "is", "my", "array");
my $json_str = encode_json(\@arr);  # This will work now

print "$json_str";
```

Outputs

```
["this","is","my","array"]
```